# Does Spring-Roo provide sort function for finders?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm using Spring-roo to build my project, it's a very great tool. But when I want to sort the entities on GUI, I cannot find a sort support in generated finders. I don't want to modify these auto-generated files, so I ask here anyone knows how to add sort function in finders or in some other ways? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some options for sorting in the comments for spring roo jira issue: ROO-158.  You can find the link [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-158)